# SSRS 2008 R2 Shared Datasource References Gone

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2010, reporting-services

I have a farm with SharePoint 2010 integrated mode SSRS 2008 R2. A few days ago, one night at about 02:00 AM, almost all shared data source references had gone. I couldn't find any clue at neither SharePoint nor SSRS. I did create almost all report connection references manually but still don't know why they had gone.

[image: Error]

I found [this post](http://blogs.lobsterpot.com.au/2012/10/09/when-someone-deletes-a-shared-data-source-in-ssrs/) and situations are similar but at my situation, nobody removed shared data source references or connections. They have just gone.

*Is there anybody who knows the reason or gives me the insight of where to look at for further information?*

Comment: anything in the SharePoint logs or SQL logs?

Comment: Unfortunately, nothing in the logs :/

Comment: was not there any installed update?

Comment: Nope :/ I'm looking for SQL Server Builds. It could be a bug :/